# How do you get a response from google sheets when using gsheets in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-sheets

How do you get an actual response informing that inserting a row has failed or has succeeded?

I want to update the local database only if inserting a row has been successful. But, when I run the method below even without an internet connection, it shows uploading to be successful which undoubtedly isn't the case.

`static Future insert(List<Map<String, dynamic>> rowList) async { // check if worksheet exists if (_userSheet == null) return; _userSheet!.values.map.appendRows(rowList); }`